# Quartz job for Grails cannot update record

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have following Quartz job in my Grails application:

```
class DataWarehouseJob {

    def execute(context) {

        LeadList list = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('list')

        if (list.processing) {
            return
        }

        list.processing = true
        list.save(failOnError: true)

        ...

    }
}
```

`list` is passed as a parameter on job `triggerNow` call and it's populated with correct values. This list already exists in database. However, when it tries to save the list, following error occurs:

```
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [haystack.LeadList#169]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [haystack.LeadList#169]
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [haystack.LeadList#169]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [haystack.LeadList#169]

...

Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [haystack.LeadList#169]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:618)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:301)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:244)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:109)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90
...
```

I have tried adding `flush: true` as parameter to save function, calling `merge` on list before save, annotating class with `@ExecuteInJTATransaction`, saving LeadList `withNewSession`, but nothing helped - same error always occurs on same line (`list.save`)

The weirdest thing is that this code worked before and I'm not sure which change could break it - there were no commits of changes touching this class in quite some time.

The code is written in Grails 3.1.5 and running on Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't wanna delete the question, since solution might benefit someone.

The problem was because job was accepting the `LeadList` object and I guess it created the copy of it instead of passing the object by reference, and that's what caused the problem.

**Solution** is to send ID of the object as a parameter to job instead of the whole object, and in job to first fetch object by ID before making changes in database:

```
// LeadList list = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('list')
long listId = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('listId')
LeadList list = LeadList.findById(listId)
```

Still, I have no idea how passing the whole object worked before and then at some point started causing the issue all of a sudden.